# SVN+SSH into specific volume on OS X

Tags: svn, ssh, osx-server

I'm trying to access a svn repo on an OS X (snow leopard) server. The sys admin created a new volume on that machine (volume name is "svn") just for svn repositories.

On the svn volume, I created a directory called "repo". In repo, I created a repository called "test".

I'm trying to access the test repo using tortoiseSVN installed on a WinXP box.
The connection looks like...

svn+ssh://server.name.org/svn/repo/test

It seems to authenticate ok, but tells me it can't find a repository there.

What am I doing wrong?

I assume it's something to do with addressing the volume name incorrectly, but I'm drawing a compete blank for how to tell ssh what volume on that machine to mount.

Thanks.

Comment: You're saying that he mounted it as `/svn`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the local path to the repository `/svn/repo/test`? I would assume that if you've got a volume named svn it would be in `/Volumes` and you'd use `svn+ssh://server.name.org/Volumes/svn/repo/test` to connect to it.

Answer (score 1):

Doh.

svn+ssh://server.name.org/Volumes/svn/repo/test

This works.

I feel like such an idiot.